# 18.04 machine doing nfs mount of file on 19.10 machine

Tags: 18.04, 19.10, nfs

nfs mount from 18.04 to 19.10 gets "access denied by server while mounting willie12:/Data12-1". An nfs mount to an 18.04 machine works OK.
The mount command is as follows "sudo mount -t nfs willie12:/Data12-1 /Data12-1". The uid for both root and user bill are the same on both machines.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the setup of the 19.10 machine. It is not starting the nfs server. I am working on that but have not managed to get it to start at boot time yet.

Comment: I finally got the nfs server to start at boot time.